# Split csv column in subcolumns using numpy dtype and converters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a csv file with some columns containing a measured value including error values. I want to import everything to python using numpy genfromtxt and format my array by using dtype. Let's assume I have a csv file in this format:

```
# Name, Time, Intensity
Sample1, 300, 1000+-5
Sample2, 300, 1500+-2
```

I want to parse the whole file and split value and uncertainty into two subcolumns of the column Intensity. I defined two dtypes:

```
import numpy as np
TypeValErr = np.dtype([("value", np.int32), ("error", np.int32)])
TypeCSV=np.dtype({"names": ["name", "time", "intensity"],
                  "formats": ["U32", np.int32, TypeValErr],
                  "titles": ["Name", "Time", "Intensity"]})
```

Using this dtypes, I first create just a test array by myself:

```
Intensity = np.array([(2000, 12)], dtype=TypeValErr)
CSVentry = np.array([("Sample3", 300, Intensity)], dtype=TypeCSV)

print(CSVentry)
```

Which gives me the expected output

```
[('Sample3', 300, (2000, 12))]
```

In the next step, I want to import the CSV using this dtype. As the Intensity column has the wrong format, I want to use a converter to convert the output into the right format:

```
def convertToValErrArr(txt):
    splitted = txt.split("+-")
    return np.array([(splitted[0], splitted[1])], dtype=TypeValErr)

print(np.array([("Sample3", 300, convertToValErrArr("1800+-7"))], dtype=TypeCSV))
```

The output gives again the expected

```
[('Sample3', 300, (1800, 7))]
```

But finally, the import itself throws an error. Here is my code:

```
ConvertFunc = lambda x: convertToValErrArr(x)

file = np.genfromtxt("test.csv",
                     delimiter=",",
                     autostrip=True,
                     dtype=TypeCSV,
                     skip_header=1,
                     converters={2: lambda x: convertToValErrArr(str(x))})
```

And here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvimport.py", line 28, in <module>
    converters={2: lambda x: convertToValErrArr(str(x))})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1896, in genfromtxt
    rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.
```

I don't see the mistake. Is genfromtxt processing the data in a different way? I hope, somebody has an idea! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've tested a converter that splits a field into two, and couldn't get it to work.  I won't say it's impossible, but that's not the intended use of converters.  But we'd have to study `genfromtxt` to see why it fails, and if there's any fudge.

Comment: Does your `TypeCSV` work with a 4 column file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your dtype, and 4 columns, it works (nested dtype and all)

```
In [58]: TypeValErr = np.dtype([("value", np.int32), ("error", np.int32)])
    ...: TypeCSV=np.dtype({"names": ["name", "time", "intensity"],
    ...:                   "formats": ["U32", np.int32, TypeValErr],
    ...:                   "titles": ["Name", "Time", "Intensity"]})
    ...: 
In [59]: txt=b"""# Name, Time, Intensity
    ...: Sample1, 300, 1000, 5
    ...: Sample2, 300, 1500, 2"""
In [60]: 
In [60]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=TypeCSV, delimiter=',',skip_header=True)
In [61]: data
Out[61]: 
array([('Sample1', 300, (1000, 5)), ('Sample2', 300, (1500, 2))], 
      dtype=[(('Name', 'name'), '<U32'), (('Time', 'time'), '<i4'), (('Intensity', 'intensity'), [('value', '<i4'), ('error', '<i4')])])
```

So it is able to take a flat list of values, e.g. `['Sample1', 300, 1000, 5]` and map them on the nested tuples need to save this dtype:
`('Sample1', 300, (1000, 5))`.

But the converter does not turn `['Sample1', '300', '1000+-5']` into `['Sample1', '300', (1000, 5)]`, or if it does it isn't the right thing for subsequent use.

`dtype_flat` in the error message is:

```
In [70]: np.lib.npyio.flatten_dtype(TypeCSV)
Out[70]: [dtype('<U32'), dtype('int32'), dtype('int32'), dtype('int32')]
```

So your nested dtype is produced with an sequence like this:

```
In [75]: rows=np.array(('str',1,2, 3),dtype=[('',_) for _ in np.lib.npyio.flatten_dtype(TypeCSV)])
In [76]: rows.view(TypeCSV)
Out[76]: 
array(('str', 1, (2, 3)), 
      dtype=[(('Name', 'name'), '<U32'), (('Time', 'time'), '<i4'), (('Intensity', 'intensity'), [('value', '<i4'), ('error', '<i4')])])
```

In fact there's a comment to that effect just before the error line

```
    if len(dtype_flat) > 1:
        # Nested dtype, eg [('a', int), ('b', [('b0', int), ('b1', 'f4')])]
        # First, create the array using a flattened dtype:
        # [('a', int), ('b1', int), ('b2', float)]
        # Then, view the array using the specified dtype.
        if 'O' in (_.char for _ in dtype_flat):
        ...
        else:
            rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
            output = rows.view(dtype)
```

`data` at this point is a list of 'row` tuples, which have already been passed through the converters:

```
rows = list(
        zip(*[[conv._strict_call(_r) for _r in map(itemgetter(i), rows)]
              for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]))
```

simplified the conversion process is

```
In [84]: converters = [str, int, int, int]
In [85]: row = ['one','1','2','3']
In [86]: [conv(r) for conv, r in zip(converters, row)]
Out[86]: ['one', 1, 2, 3]
```

but actually closer to:

```
In [87]: rows = [row,row]
In [88]: rows
Out[88]: [['one', '1', '2', '3'], ['one', '1', '2', '3']]
In [89]: from operator import itemgetter
In [90]: [[conv(r) for r in map(itemgetter(i), rows)] for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]
Out[90]: [['one', 'one'], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
In [91]: list(zip(*_))
Out[91]: [('one', 1, 2, 3), ('one', 1, 2, 3)]
```

So the long and short is that `converters` cannot split a column into 2 or more columns.  The process of splitting, converting, and then mapping onto the dtype occurs in the wrong order for this.  What I demonstrated at the start is probably easist - pass your file, line by line through a text processing line.  It would replace the `+-` with the specified delimiter.   Then the file will have the correct number of columns to work with your dtype.